# Is there a tool for interactions versioning?

Tags: sharing, version-control

I'm looking for a tool to make it possible to share different versions of interactions between several screens. Is there anything like that on the market that can help? I tried several tools like inVision or Abstract and it's not possible to achieve that.

Comment: Do you mean as code or as visual diagram based prototypes?

Answer (score 1):

There is plant for sketch ( https://plantapp.io ) and versions ( https://versions.sympli.io ) that do exactly what you want

Answer (score 0):

[Framer](https://framer.com/) files are basically websites, therefore you could use [Git](https://git-scm.com/) to version the code. 
You could also save different versions of your interaction to the framer cloud and share them.